# [SQL Server]Column 'retailers.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using laravel with mssql and getting this error with simple group by query.
RetailersModel::groupBy('state')->get();

And it returns me error.
I have migrating database server from mysql to mssql.
Mysql is running fine but error occur when try to get record from ms-sql database server.

I have also set strict false in mysql and mssql config in database php.

Thanks in advance.

```
RetailersModel::groupBy('state')->get();
```

Comment: Please share the whole query with us, not just the group by,

Comment: I suspect you are selecting more fields and only grouping by one field. Previous versions of MySQL were relaxed about grouping like this, which is why it works in MySQL. Try adding retailers.id to the group by.

Comment: @Thailo This is the complete query in laravel Eloquent

Comment: @SyedHussim Thanks for the suggestion but I am using Ms-sql server database. It works like a charm with mysql.

Comment: @niraj I understand, but the point I am making is that, MySQL is less strict on group by . On MySQL you can do group by on one field but in other database systems this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this query

```
  RetailersModel::select('*','state', DB::raw('COUNT(state) as state'))->groupBy('state')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this will work but my concern is to select all the columns of table.

Comment: @nirajrahi I have updated my answer, see if it is selecting all records.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but I have tried all these possible queries but it does not work. Also it says to add aggregate function for every column like max,min or other functions.